# Pencil of Curves on a Surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a projective surface. A ***pencil of curves with base $B$*** is a dominant rational map $\pi: X \dashrightarrow B$ such that $k(B)$ is algebraically closed in $k(X)$.

But we also have a definition that a pencil is a one dimensional linear system. I want to know if these two definitions compatible?

My guess is that the first definition is the generalization of $\mathbb P^1$ to arbitrary $B$. But I have no idea how to prove this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are related, but not the same. Given a one dimensional linear system, you get a rational map from $X\to \mathbb{P}^1$, which becomes a morphism only after blowing up the base points of the linear system. Given a non-constant morphism $f:X\to\mathbb{P}^1$ (so $X$ may have been replaced with a blow-up), you can use Stein factorization to factorize and get $X\stackrel{\pi}{\to} B\stackrel{h}{\to}\mathbb{P}^1$ with $h\circ \pi=f$ and $\pi$ as in your first situation.

Comment: This makes sense. But in the first definition we require the function field extension is algebraically closed, while here you get $\pi: X \to B$ with connected fibers. Could you explain a little bit how they are related?

Comment: @Akatsuki The algebraic closed condition is precisely what Stein factorization achieves and equivalent to the fact that generic fiber is geometrically irreducible.